# Magento: how to merge two product collections into one?

Tags: collections, magento

if i have two product collections is there a way to merge them into one?

for example (my final intent isn't to actually just get a collection of 2 cats, this is just to illustrate the issue):

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(148)->getProductCollection();
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(149)->getProductCollection();

$merged_collection = merge_collections($collection1,$collection2);
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming the items you wish to group together are of the same type and exist in the database then you can do this:

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(148)->getProductCollection();
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(149)->getProductCollection();

$merged_ids = array_merge($collection1->getAllIds(), $collection2->getAllIds());
// can sometimes use "getLoadedIds()" as well

$merged_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Here I know to filter by `entity_id` because that is products' key field, like it is for most entity types, some flat tables have a different primary key. Often you can generalise that with one of the collection's `getIdFieldName()` method. Products are a bad example in this case because it's ID field name isn't filled out correctly.

Comment: This requires 3 database queries, but haltabush solution requires only 2 database queries. I wouldn't use this if there are not extra filters  or sortings needed for combined collections.

Comment: A side note.. `addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids)` will translate to `WHERE (entity_id = 1001) OR (entity_id = 1002) OR (entity_id = 1003) OR (entity_id = 1004) OR ....`

  which is slower than `IN(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004)` that is generated by `addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids)) `

Answer (score 15):

Almost every (or every?) collection in Magento inherits from a [Varien Data Collection](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections).  A collection is a special object that holds objects of another type.  There's no method for merging collections, but you can add additional items of the appropriate type to the collection.

Code like this should get you where you want to go, although there's probably more efficient ways to loop and do the actual merging.

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(148)->getProductCollection();
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(149)->getProductCollection();

//load an empty collection (filter-less collections will auto-lazy-load everything)
$merged = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',-1);

//add items from the first collection
foreach($collection1 as $item)
{
    $merged->addItem($item);
}

//add items from the second collection
foreach($collection2 as $item)
{               
    //magento won't let you add two of the same thing to a collection
    //so make sure the item doesn't already exist
    if(!$merged->getItemById($item->getId())) 
    {
        $merged->addItem($item);
    }           
}

//lets make sure we got something
foreach($merged as $product)
{
    var_dump($product->getName());
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that you risk to get an exception: `Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "***" already exist`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is such a method, but you can probably do something like that :

```
foreach ($collection1 as $item){
    $collection2->addElem($item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can filter your collection directly without using 2.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_collection = $products->getCollection();
->addCategoryFilter(2)
->load();
```

or try using 'addItem' to add your results to a collection. See also in [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

Comment: i can't filter since i'll be getting the collections two different ways and wont be able to add one filter to it. I tried addItem before but when passing that off to the left hand nav & listing page the counts get all messed up.

Comment: oh im sorry, I didnt know that. Have you tried instead of merging two collections, to create a third one depending on data of your previous collections? (e.g. id's)

Answer (score -1):

for the collection of products of several categories, you can use the following code

```
      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            'catalog_category_product',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            array('category_id')
            )
        ->where('catalog_category_product.category_id IN (?)', $categories);
```