# Magento Merge 2 Categories Into 1 Collection

Tags: magento

I have a site that sells car parts.  I have set up my categories to be Make -> Model -> Year, from here the filtering is done by attributes.  Brakes, Wheels, Engine etc…

This filters the collection as I’d expect, but once I get to the Year I want to also include items from a Universal Category.  I.E. The collection should include items for a particular car, plus “Universal” items across all cars.

I found this [Magento: how to merge two product collections into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434996/magento-how-to-merge-two-product-collections-into-one) which seems to be what I want, but I can’t seem to figure out exactly where this should be implemented.

There are getCollection() methods in List.php, Layer.php and Category.php and I’ve tried to implement the code in the link above but with no success.  If I include it in List.php the collections seem to be merged, but the attribute filtering isn’t applied on the Universal products.

I've tried editing the getProductCollection function in Category.php like so:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    //return $collection;

    $universalCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(18)->getProductCollection();

    $merged_ids = array_merge($collection->getAllIds(), $universalCollection->getAllIds());
    // can sometimes use "getLoadedIds()" as well

    $merged_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    return $merged_collection;
}
```

But this gives me: "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting!"

If anyone can give any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a fatal error because you are causing an infinite loop to occur.

This is simply due to the fact that your code sits inside the Category model getProductCollection() method and you are calling getProductCollection() on a new category model again.  This is resulting in an infinite loop

So, you need to move that code out of there.  **You really should not be editing these core files the way you are currently anyway.**

Its entirely up to you how you extend the model: rewrite, observer etc.  But just dont change the Magento core code.

I have provided an working example below which merges two category product collections, externally to the category model:

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $categoryOneId = 10;
    $categoryTwoId = 13;

    $categoryOne = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryOneId);
    $categoryTwo = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryTwoId);

    $collectionOne = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addCategoryFilter($categoryOne);

    $collectionTwo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addCategoryFilter($categoryTwo);

    $merged_ids = array_merge($collectionOne->getAllIds(), $collectionTwo->getAllIds());

    $mergedCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, I understand that I shouldn't be editing core files.  The plan was to get it working in some form and then do it properly later.  Whether that would happen or not is another thing... lol...

Thanks for all your help, I'm sure I can figure it out from this.

Comment: Hi Drew, when I use this code, my attribute filters don't seem to work.  I get a whole load of items with no name, a cost of 0.00 and Out of Stock and then the items relevant to the filters.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnCondron - try using addAttributeToSelect on the merged collection with your required attributes or * for all i.e. addAttributeToSelect(array('price', 'name')) or addAttributeToSelect('*') etc