# About Magento pagination after $collection->removeItemByKey

Tags: magento, collections, pagination, product

I follow this blog, it is very reliable and I find good solutions ..
This time, however, I have not found a solution to my problem, so I decided to post the problem I have with magento:
I had to apply a filter to the collection of products in list.php, the code is as follows:

foreach ($ collection as $ key => $ product){

```
             $ _regularPrice = $ _taxHelper-> getPrice ($ product, $ product-> getPrice (), $ _simplePricesTax);
             $ _finalPrice = $ _taxHelper-> getPrice ($ product, $ product-> getFinalPrice ());
             $ discount = floor (($ _regularPrice - $ _finalPrice) / $ _regularPrice * 100);

             if ($ discount <50) {
                 $ collection-> removeItemByKey ($ key);
             }
```

}

this is done, I have my own collection of products to be displayed, now it remains the problem of paging of these results, so how are you now, shows me around 300 products in the first page, and the link of the pager shows about 8 pages, how can I do to have the same functionality that offers magento to its lists by default?
Thanks for any help
Greetings to all Luke

Answer (score 1):

Since you have some maths on the go in there I don't think you will be able to do it in the code for the collection. What you can do is iterate the collection and put all the matching ids together in some huge array. Then load another collection object from those ids. This should then be paginatable.

See the SO Q/A on merging collections for how to assemble ids and load a collection with them.

[Magento: how to merge two product collections into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434996/magento-how-to-merge-two-product-collections-into-one)

Comment: IRIS Indigo Hi, thank you for answering, I looked at the link, I applied the merger of two collections, the first setting as:
$ merged = Mage :: getModel ('catalog / product') -> getCollection () -> addFieldToFilter ('entity_id', -1);
so that it remains empty, and then adding the Item in my collection, as a result I've had it a huge list in my first page and I do not have the link of the pagination after the list (this may be because magento played well the number of items in the collection), any other suggestions?
thanks
regards luke

Comment: Did you see the first answer with the array building? Sorry if I did not make that clear: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439169/1617149